# After sorting HashMap by Keys, how can I sort by Values if Keys Match

Tags: java

So using a TreeMap, I was able to sort my HashMap by keys (dates), but the next thing that I was to accomplish is that if the date is the same, then I want to sort by values (time). Could someone suggest how to get this done?

Here is the relevant code that sorts correctly by key:

```
public void eventList(){

    int year = -1;
    if(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().equals(null)){
        System.out.println("Your calendar is empty!");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Here are your events: ");
        SortedSet<GregorianCalendar> keys = new TreeSet<GregorianCalendar>(MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().keySet());

        for(GregorianCalendar key : keys){
            Event value = MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(key);
            if(value.endTime != null){
                if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){

                    System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                            + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                            + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);

                }else{
                    System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                            + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " - " + value.endTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
                            + ":" + value.endTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName );
                    year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                }

            }else{
                if(key.get(Calendar.YEAR) == year){
                    System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                            + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + value.eventName);

                }else{
                    System.out.println(key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    System.out.println(MyCalendarTester.arrayOfDays[key.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1] + ", " + MyCalendarTester.arrayOfMonths[key.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1] + " "
                            + key.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + value.startTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + value.startTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE)  + " " + value.eventName);
                    System.out.println();
                    year = key.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: A TreeMap is already a SortedMap. How did you snags to sort a HashMap to TreeMap other than by passing the HashMap to the TreeMap constructor?

Comment: Besides, your map value should be a Set of time so that it's sorted.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I'm not sure that I understand what you mean. My HashMap contains both a key(gregoriancalendar) and value (event). The key is a date and the event contains the time. I have sorted based on the dates of events, but now, if I have events on the same dates, I want to sort them by time.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom Comparator that embeds the two components of the key

```
(date, time).
```

This way your data is sorted by date first and then time.

You would achieve this by combining the (date, time) into a Tuple and then using the Tuple compareTo within the Comparator.

**UPDATE**
Another  option if you do not wish to change the key entries (which is btw a common pattern in map/reduce for secondary sorting..):   make your value entries a sorted collection and iteratively compare the collection entries.

The comparison can be done by the

```
merge()
```

logic of mergesort:  the two lists need to be sorted individually descending. Then begin to merge the lists. The difference here is that as soon as any difference were found then return the list that contains a given entry

Comment: The key doesn't contain the time, only my values contain the time. I have a compareTo() method that  can compare the time, but I only wish to invoke it if the dates are identical.

Comment: I have updated to include two options. If you want to go the other direction then you will need to make your value entries a sorted collection and iteratively compare the collection entries.

Comment: Hmm I think the second option would be simpler due to the fact that I would have to change a lot of other parts in my program if I went with changing the keys. Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "iteratively compare the collection entries"?

Comment: updated the answer about how to use two sorted lists and then a portion of the merge() to find the earlier of the two lists (or later depending on your needs)

Comment: Sorry, this is probably going to be stupid, but does Java have a merge() method? Do you have a link to an API that I can use or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using your own code rather than hoping for something native. I suggest code along the lines of this pseudo-code:

```
Declare another HashMap appropriately
for each pair in the first HashMap
  if it's next in the order, add it to the second, sorted HashMap
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code that will sort all Event objects based on date-time,

```
//* add a comparable to your event class
 public class Event implements Comparable
 {
  Calendar endTime = .....

  .....................


  public int compareTo(Object o)
  {
    Event  event = (Event)o;
    long  eventTime = event.endTime.getTimeInMillis();

    long time = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
    return (int)(time - eventTime);
  }
 }

//* loop over all of your event objects and add the correct date
for(GregorianCalendar key : keys)
{
   Event value = MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().get(key);
   value.endTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, key.get(Calendar.YEAR));
   value.endTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, key.get(Calendar.MONTH));
   value.endTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, key.get(DAY_OF_MONTH));
}
//* get the array of all events and sort them
Event[] events = (Event[])MyCalendarTester.myCal.getMyCalHash().values().toArray(new Event[0]);
Arrays.sort(events);
```